# Run a batch file on Windows, from browser but without inheriting browser's environment variables

Tags: windows, batch-file, environment-variables

I'm trying to write a Windows batch file that kicks off a setup program for internal users at my company.  There is a link to the batch file on our intranet.  If you click the link (at least on IE9, which I must support) then it asks if you want to Run or Save the file.  Most users click Run, and the batch file executes as a child process of IE, inheriting its environment variables.  This is where my problem arises.

If the browser has been open for a while, it's possible that a (user or system level) environment variable has been set on the user's PC *after* the browser was launched, so the batch file doesn't see that variable, and I need it to.

I want to find a way to make sure the batch file always runs with a fresh environment.

This works

```
rem bootstrap batch file
explorer the_real_batch_file.bat
```

because `Explorer.exe` is alert to user and system environment variable changes, but this doesn't

```
rem bootstrap batch file
explorer the_real_batch_file.bat some_param
```

The `some_param` confuses Windows Explorer (and it just launches a new Windows Explorer window).  I need to be able to pass parameters to the 'real' batch file, so this is a show-stopper.

Can anyone see a way around this?

Comment: `start explorer the_real_batch_file` instead, so it becomes a new separate process? system variables should ALWAYS show up in a new procress, even if the new process is launched from something before those new vars were set.

Comment: System environment variables don't work like that.  I just tried it from a command shell: execute a batch file that echoes some non-existent var, like `%WIBBLE%`.  Nothing echoes.  Then add a sys env var called `WIBBLE` and set it to `some text`, then, from the same command shell run the batch file again - still no echo.

Comment: explorer doesn't get restarted when you set an env var, so I fail to see how ANY new process in windows could get a new env var without a full reboot if this were the case.

Comment: And `start explorer the_real_batch_file some_text` just loads Windows Explorer (it must be giving up on the args and going back to default behaviour).  I imagine it thinks some_text is another arg to `explorer`.  Judicious quoting didn't help either.

Comment: `explorer` monitors the environment. You can watch it pick up changes to the environment using Process Explorer.  At least, if you set the env using `setx`. It must poke `explorer` in some way.

Comment: hence me saying to use `start explorer` instead, which fires up a brand new explorer, independently.

Comment: Yeah, but in my question I specify that I want to execute a batch file with a parameter passed to it.  And starting explorer that way it won't accept that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up simplifying my problem slightly. I am now able to run `start explorer my_batch_file` (without arguments to the batch file) because I generate a bespoke intermediate batch file in `%TEMP%` containing the arguments I need.

So I do this:

```
start explorer %TEMP%\temp_batch_file.bat
```

And inside `temp_batch_file.bat` I have

```
call my_original_batch_file.bat some_argument
```

This seems to work fine.

Answer (score 2):

I am sorry, I'm new here and cannot figure out for the life of me to add a comment to the question above...

Either way, explorer.exe doesn't handle the execution of batch files, cmd /c does.

Try doing

```
cmd /c "batchfile.bat argument"
```

An alternative is to figure out which enviornmental variables are being called in your software and call them in the batch to ensure that they are correct, and fail if not. IE

```
IF "%ENVIORMENTALVARIABLE%" NEQ "WhatitShouldBe" (goto :fail) else goto continue
:fail
echo this failed <insert exitcode here>
:continue
```

Comment: Ok, so I can see add comment under my answer, but not under your question.

Comment: `cmd /c "batchfile.bat argument"` doesn't work - it still runs the batch file in a child command shell, and since it is just a child process it inherits the parent environment.

Comment: on the commenting issue, that's because you don't have enough SO reputation yet. :)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Perhaps you can create a schtask to run the file and it shouldn't start it as a child process.

   `SCHTASKS /Create /sc ONCE /st 0:00:00 /sd 01/01/2050 /tn runOnce /tr "cmd /c batchfile.bat argument"
    SCHTASKS /Run /TN runOnce`

Comment: Hmm, interesting.  I want to run this task _immediately_ and the `/st 00:00:00` means 'at midnight' rather than in 0 seconds.  Sorry I just realised you have two commands there - one to set it up, one to run it  I'll try that...

Comment: This was a good idea, but it has a problem for me: I want the task to be deleted immediately after its first run and trying to the `/Z` parameter to `schtasks` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to find another way to make this work, but in the future if you ever want to use schtasks to call the batch, then delete it, you can simply do this edit:
`start /wait cmd /c SCHTASKS /Run /TN runOnce
    &  SCHTASKS /delete /TN runOnce`

Comment: The reason /z did not work, is because that flag is designed to mark the task for deletion after  "it's final run", which in our case would of been in the year 2050